# cannot get state variable of a contract deployed from a factory contract in truffle

Tags: solidity, truffle, contract-deployment

Hello I have 2 smart contracts - Children Factory and Child:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.6;
import "./Child.sol";

contract ChildrenFactory {
      
      Child[] public children;
      address[] public childrenAddresses;

    event ChildCreated(address newChild);

      function createChild(uint age) public {
         Child child = new Child(age);
         emit ChildCreated(address(child));
         children.push(child);
         childrenAddresses.push(address(child));
      }
}
```

```
pragma solidity 0.8.6;

contract Child {
     uint public age;
     address public childAddress;
     
     constructor(uint _age) {
        age = _age;
        childAddress = address(this);
     }

     function getAge() public view returns(uint childAge) {
         childAge = age;
     }
}
```

I migrated the factory contract in truffle and ran the following code:

```
let instance = await ChildrenFactory.deployed()
instance.createChild(5) // I got the address of the new child contract from the tx log
let child1 = await Child.at('the address from the tx')
await child1.getAge() // results in an error
```

both getAge and age() return the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing
> transaction: revert.

As far as I know, this was supposed to be the right way to interact with contracts deployed from the factory but apparently, it is not and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I would very much appreciate every help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following :

1. Open the truffle development console at the root of your truffle project with the command `truffle develop`
2. Deploy the `ChildrenFactory` smart contract with `truffle migrate --reset`

My migration file is :

```
const ChildrenFactory = artifacts.require("ChildrenFactory");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
deployer.deploy(ChildrenFactory);
};
```

3. Get the `ChildrenFactory` contract instance

   ```
   let instance = await ChildrenFactory.deployed()
   ```
4. Deploy the `Child` smart contract

   ```
   let tx = await instance.createChild(5)
   ```
5. From the transaction receipt, get the address of the `Child` contract.

Use `tx.logs` and see the address given inside the `args` field (or use `tx.logs[0].args[0]` to get the address directly).

6. Get the `Child` contract instance

   ```
   let child1 = await Child.at('the address from the tx receipt')
   ```
7. Call the function of the `Child` contract

   ```
   await child1.getAge()
   ```

It will return `BN { negative: 0, words: [ 5, <1 empty item> ], length: 1, red: null }` with the value returned by the smart contract in the `words` field.